# Localization in DITA

Tags: xml, dita

I am organizing a localized documentation for internal use in more languages.

Basically an argument is divided in topics grouped by a ditamap.

Let's say this is the structure:

1. description (topic)
2. history (topic)
3. problems (topic)

Then, each topic has a title and a text.

```
<topic id="topic_gbq_tdy_wr">
  <title>Title in specific language</title>
  <body>
    <p>lot of text here....</p>
  </body>
</topic>
```

In all cases Title is a static label, that should be changed at build time by the tools, with a localized value.

Ideally if I have product A, I would have `productA_it.dita` and `productA_en.dita`, both of them with title correctly localized. And so on for product B, it would have same kind topics but localized title.

How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if I correctly understand what you are trying to achieve. I assume, you're using the [DITA-OT](http://www.dita-ot.org). If you transform your maps or topics, the DITA-OT injects text defined in localized XML files. You can add or modify text, like it is explained [here](http://www.dita-ot.org/1.8/dev_ref/plugin-addgeneratedtext.html).

If you like to have standard text phrases, you can store them keys (one file per language) and swap these files, when you need that.

**myMap.ditamap**

A map with a *String* file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE map PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Map//EN" "map.dtd">
<map>
  <title>Title of Your Map</title>

  <!-- Reference to a Topic -->
  <topicref href="myTopic.dita"/>

  <!-- Your Key Files -->
  <topicref keys="myStrings" href="myStringsEN.dita" processing-role="resource-only"/>
  <!--<topicref keys="myStrings" href="myStringsDE.dita" processing-role="resource-only"/>-->
</map>
```

**myStringsEN.dita**

Your *String* file. It contains [ph](http://docs.oasis-open.org/dita/v1.2/os/spec/langref/ph.html#ph) elements, that can be referenced in many elements, like [title](http://docs.oasis-open.org/dita/v1.2/os/spec/langref/title.html) or [p](http://docs.oasis-open.org/dita/v1.2/os/spec/langref/p.html).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE topic PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Topic//EN" "topic.dtd">
<topic id="myStrings">
  <title>My Strings EN</title>
  <body>
    <p>
      <ph id="myFristString">HELLO</ph>
      <ph id="mySecondString">WORLD</ph>
    </p>
  </body>
</topic>
```

**myTopic.dita**

Your *Topic* file containing the [ph](http://docs.oasis-open.org/dita/v1.2/os/spec/langref/ph.html#ph) references with [conkeyref](http://docs.oasis-open.org/dita/v1.2/os/spec/common/theconkeyrefattribute.html#theconkeyrefattribute) attributes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE topic PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Topic//EN" "topic.dtd">
<topic id="myTopic">
  <title>My Topic</title>
  <body>
    <p><ph conkeyref="myStrings/myFristString"/></p>
    <p><ph conkeyref="myStrings/mySecondString"/></p>
  </body>
</topic>
```

Hope that helps...